# Laravel Validation: One required input that can come from either of two fields

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I have `upload_media` and `url`. `upload_media` is where you have to upload a .pdf file,  and `url` if you want a url.

so what I want is that, if `upload_media` is not empty then, `url` should not be required. If the user decided to use the `url`, then the `upload_media` will not be required. But if either of them doesn't have a value then it should return a required error.

Here is my validation:

```
   $this->validate($request, [
        'title'              => 'required',
        'viewing_time'       => 'required',
        'tags'               => '',
        'description'        => '',
        'organization'       => '',
        'upload_media'       => '',
        'url'                => '',
        'upload_preview'     => 'required|file|image'
    ]);
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `required_without` rule: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title'              => 'required',
    'viewing_time'       => 'required',
    'tags'               => '',
    'description'        => '',
    'organization'       => '',
    'upload_media'       => 'required_without:url',
    'url'                => 'required_without:upload_media',
    'upload_preview'     => 'required|file|image'
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$rules = [
    'title'              => 'required',
    'viewing_time'       => 'required',
    'tags'               => '',
    'description'        => '',
    'organization'       => '',
    'upload_media'       => 'required',
    'url'                => 'required',
    'upload_preview'     => 'required|file|image'
];

if ($request->file('upload_media')->isValid()) {
    $rules['url'] = '';
} elseif (!empty($request->get('url'))) {
    $rules['upload_media'] = '';
}

$this->validate($request, $rules);
```